# How to convert pandas.core.series.Series type to 2D array?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to train a model using KNNClassifier. I split the data as follows:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_bow, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

y_train= y_train.astype('int')

neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
neigh.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When I try to test it, I get a value error.

```
pre = neigh.predict(y_test)

Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0. 1. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a 
single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

My y_test is of type ***pandas.core.series.Series***

So how do I convert pandas.core.series.Series to array of 2D to make this testing work?

I have tried to convert y_test to dataframe and then to array, but I get another value error and I am stuck.

```
y_test = pd.DataFrame(y_test)
y_test = y_test.as_matrix().reshape(-1,1)
pre = neigh.predict(y_test)

ValueError: Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: X.shape[1] == 1 while Y.shape[1] == 6038
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to use your `X_test` variable / array, not `y_test`.

`X_test` are the `independent` variables / features used to test the accuracy of our model, and `y_test` are the actual `target` values which will be compared with the predicted values.

Example:

```
pre = neigh.predict(X_test)
```

To measure accuracy:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(y_test, pre)
```